# Accessing folders in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, directory

Sorry, complete beginner here with AppleScripting.

I'm trying to do a very simple thing, move files from one folder to another.

```
tell application "Finder"

    set this_folder to "Users:chris.nicol:Movies:SmartConverter:"

    set this_list to every file of this_folder
    repeat with i in this_list
        --if i does not start with "x" then
        move i to "users:chris.nicol:music:itunes:itunes media:automatically add to itunes:"
        --end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

However I keep getting an error:

[image]

I've tried different commands (count, parentContainer, etc.) on the folder, but I get the same type of error.  I've tried different formatting for the folder ...

- Users/chris.nicol/Movies/SmartConverter/
- Macintosh HD:Users:chris.nicol:Movies:SmartConverter
- etc.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple tip... if you want to find the proper path you should use try this and look in the results field for the proper path. You'll see that the name of the hard drive, Macintosh HD, is required. Note you could use "choose file" as well if you wanted the path to a file.

```
(choose folder) as text
```

Next, the path that you will see is a string. Applescript sees it as a string not a path to a file or folder. As such, when you want to use the string as a path then you must put the word "file" or "folder" in front of it as appropriate to make applescript use it properly. Therefore your script should look like this. Note that the move command can handle a list of files so the repeat loop isn't needed.

```
set this_folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:chris.nicol:Movies:SmartConverter:"
tell application "Finder"
    set this_list to every file of folder this_folder
    move this_list to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:chris.nicol:music:itunes:itunes media:automatically add to itunes:"
end tell
```

Comment: Once you have created this_list, you don't need to include folder in the move command. You can simply move this_list to "Macintosh HD:Users:chris.nicol:music:itunes:itunes media:automatically add to itunes:" as I did in my response.

Comment: Yes. However the proper technique as defined in the Finder's dictionary is to use a "location specifier" with the move command. You create a specifier by using the words "file" or "folder". Also a specifier will work anywhere where a string will only work in limited cases. So the best habit for someone is to do it the way I showed and don't worry about the special cases where something else works too. It's the same with posix paths. They work in some places but why try to remember where they work and don't work. Just use file/folder specifiers and you will always be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set thisFolder to (path to movies folder as text) & "SmartConverter"
set thatFolder to (path to music folder as text) & "itunes:itunes media:automatically add to itunes"

tell application "Finder" to move files of folder thisFolder to thatFolder
```

Answer (score -2):

You must have some invisible or otherwise uncopyable files in one of the folders. Either add something like `without invisibles` to the end of your `set this_folder` line, or get rid of your loop altogether and simply call

```
move files of entire contents of this_folder to (the Add Automatically folder)
```